# Google Apps Script write to HTML with Function

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-apps

I am trying to write a Google Apps Script that when published as a Web App will have a button, which when pressed, will call a function from Code.gs that will reveal or hide a piece of html (in effect, change the style of the div with a specific ID).

This is a small case example I've set up:

**My index.html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="google.script.run.myFunction()">Click Me</button>

  <div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV I want to Reveal/Hide.
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

**My Code.gs file:**

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index.html");
  var html = template.evaluate();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  }

function myFunction() {  
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");/*Where the Reference Error Shows Up*/
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else {
      x.style.display = "none";
      }
   }
```

The error I keep getting when debugging is: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined.  When published, the button appears with myDIV visible, and clicking the button does nothing.

I am assuming the problem is that I should not be using document.getElementByID(), but rather somethingelse.getElementByID(), but I don't know what that something else is.  Most cases that I look for online are not specific to Google Web Apps.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care about where each code is executed : the GS code is executed on "server side" and so can't refer to `document` which is a navigator ("client side") variable.

Add `myFunction()` to your HTML and call it directly with `onclick="myFunction();"`, that should do the trick.

Regards,